# Extract secret value only from SecretString using Ansible amazon.aws.aws_secret

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to get a secret value to a var from AWS Secret Manager using Ansible. My original attempt was as follows:

`mySecret: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'my/awesome/secret', region='eu-west-2')}}"`

This returns a value like:

`{"password" : "mypassword"}`

All I want is the `mypassword` value

I have tried numerous ways using `json_query` including:

`mySecret: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'my/awesome/secret', region='eu-west-2') | from_json | json_query('SecretString.password')  }}"`

But this does not return a value.

What is the correct way of extracting the value only when using json_query with Ansible?

Comment: `mypassword` is the secret value though so how would I know it?

Comment: `fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: {{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'my/awesome/secret', region='eu-west-2').password }}: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'password'"}`

Comment: I have done a debug, and as I said in the question `{"password" : "mypassword"}` is returned, literally

Thanks for your solutions, I will try them

Comment: Your suggestion above led me to the right solution;
`(lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'my/awesome/secret', region='eu-west-2') | from_json).password`

You should put this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible is very much JSON capable, it can read properly a JSON object and get you properties of the said JSON document by the dot `.` notation.

Given the JSON

```
{ 
  "secret": { 
    "password" : "mypassword" 
  } 
}
```

You can access it simply via `secret.password`, in Ansible.

Now, what it seems, from your comments, is that the lookup `amazon.aws.aws_secret` is not returning a JSON but a string, representing a JSON. So, in order to access it, you will have to use the `to_json` filter first, as you tried it, already.

But, beside that, the explanation here above still applies, so, this is what you are looking for:

```yaml
secret: >-
  {{ 
    (lookup(
      'amazon.aws.aws_secret', 
      'my/awesome/secret', 
      region='eu-west-2'
    ) | from_json).password 
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nested` parameter:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_secret_lookup.html#parameter-nested

For example:

```
mySecret: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'my/awesome/secret.password', region='eu-west-2', nested=True)}}"
```